# How to backup installed softwares in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, backup

How to backup installed software on Windows XP and restore it back to another machine.

Is there any utility to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean individually, by software package, or are you wanting to clone one PC to another, all-inclusive?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there is a utility that can do this. Each software installs files to different locations in the system, some only in the program files directory, some in other places on the system. On top of that software often writes entries to different locations in the registry and there is no way a utility can keep track of all this for all programs out there.

Your best bet is to backup the settings for each program from the programs interface if it has such an option. Look for options like "export" och "backup" in the program. This produces a file which you later can import when you reinstall the program on the other machine and all settings should be restored.

Answer (score 0):

PC Relocator can do this, no guarantee it can move every program.

[http://www.amazon.com/Pearson-Software-PC-Relocator-4-0/dp/B000063CWY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000063CWY)